# How to find out if key exist in cacheManager (org.springframework.cache.CacheManager)

Tags: spring-boot, caching, infinispan

Is there a way to see if a particular key exist in cacheManager (`org.springframework.cache.CacheManager`) as i am unable to find a way to do that as there is no `containsKey` option. I would appreciate if someone could show me a way to check if a key exist in cacheManager. Below are few things i have tried so far -

```
Cache cache=null;
for (String name : cacheManager.getCacheNames()) {
    cache=cacheManager.getCache(name);
    System.out.println("-------------->"+cache.get("dummyCache").get()); //this will give me null pointer exception as there is no dummyCache 
    }
```

I would like add if/else check to see if a `dummyCache`key exist in cache

Comment: so if i understand this right then when i do cache.get("foo") that means "foo" key already exist in cache and is not null but what if i want to check if "foo" exist in cache

Comment: Aweome that answers my question thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply check the value returned by `Cache.get` for `null`.

From the [relevant documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html#get-java.lang.Object-) (emphasis by me):

> Returns the value to which this cache maps the specified key, contained within a Cache.ValueWrapper which may also hold a cached null value. **A straight null being returned means that the cache contains no mapping for this key.**

So

- `cache.get("foo") == null` means: The key "foo" does not exist in the cache
- `cache.get("foo").get() == null` means: The key "foo" does exist in the cache, but its value is `null`